# Which one of these methods would be faster?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection with 100 million documents. I want to remove all the documents where the guildID is not in an array. I'm using NodeJS with Mongoose.

Which way would be faster?

1: Stream the whole collection and I check every time I recieve a document if the guildID is in the array. If it's not in the array I use deleteOne()

2: Use deleteMany and $nin. I am currently using this method and it is taking over 2 hours to delete 10 million documents.

Comment: how big is your array? you can store the array values in temporary collection, use `$lookup` aggregation on both collections to get documents to be deleted

Comment: @sidgate it has 200k elements

Comment: Show us the document to see the array structure and do you have any index?

Comment: Is the guildId indexed? Ideally, heavy operations like this should operate on the _id field. The second best option is to define an index on guildId. If all but a few documents shall be deleted each time, it might be worth looking discarding documents via aggregate’s $merge step rather than calling deleteMany.